# Show that the set of functions e^{ikx} is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that the functions $e^{ikx}=\cos kx +i\sin kx$ are linearly independent for $k\in\{-n,...n\}$ over either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

So far I've taken $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ and am trying to show $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{iz_1x}e^{iz_2x} dx = 0$ to show that the functions are orthogonal.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{iz_1x}e^{iz_2x} dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos z_1x+i \sin z_1x)(\cos z_2x+i \sin z_2x) dx $$
$$=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos z_1x \cos z_2x- \sin z_1x\sin z_2x)dx +i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\sin z_1x \cos z_2x+\cos z_1x \sin z_2x) dx$$
which is 0 as $\cos nx, \sin nx$ are orthogonal.

But does that help with linear independence? Or is this completely off?

There was a hint involving integration in the problem, I am just having a hard time figuring out how it leads to the result.

Comment: If this set were linearly dependent, then you could express one as a linear combination of the others.  But then its inner product with itself on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is (1) strictly positive, yet (2) zero, being a linear combination of a bunch of zeroes.  Contradiction.

Comment: Ah, cheers @vadim123 !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have proved that your functions are pairwise orthogonal, hence independent (as @vadim123 has also pointed out).